# The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities, dbfunctions

Using this code in **Entity Framework** I receive the following error. I need to get all the rows for a specific date, `DateTimeStart` is of type DataType in this format `2013-01-30 12:00:00.000`

Code:

```
 var eventsCustom = eventCustomRepository.FindAllEventsCustomByUniqueStudentReference(userDevice.UniqueStudentReference)
                    .Where(x =>  x.DateTimeStart.Date == currentDateTime.Date);
```

---

Error:

> base {System.SystemException} = {"The specified type member 'Date' is
>   not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members,
>   and entity navigation properties are supported."}

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: I am able to use x.DateTimeStart.Date  in EF Core 2.1.1

Answer (score 331, accepted):

`DateTime.Date` cannot be converted to SQL. Use [EntityFunctions.TruncateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395596.aspx) method to get date part.

```
var eventsCustom = eventCustomRepository
.FindAllEventsCustomByUniqueStudentReference(userDevice.UniqueStudentReference)
.Where(x => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DateTimeStart) == currentDate.Date);
```

UPDATE: As @shankbond mentioned in comments, in Entity Framework 6 [`EntityFunctions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is obsolete, and you should use [`DbFunctions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) class, which is shipped with Entity Framework.

Comment: I have to slight modify your version .Where(x => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DateTimeStart) == currentDate.Date); let me know your thougs

Comment: I hope you do not mind I have edit your answer adding .date if you agree, so just for reference :-) thanks for your support, I really appreciate it

Comment: @GibboK sure, no problem :) That was just for purpose of formatting long string.

Comment: EntityFunctions is obsolete, instead use DbFunctions.TruncateTime method

Comment: The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Comment: use DbFunctions.TruncateTime and EntityFunctions are deprecated.

Comment: It's block model join by foreign key.

Answer (score 107):

You should now use `DbFunctions.TruncateTime`

```
var anyCalls = _db.CallLogs.Where(r => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(r.DateTime) == callDateTime.Date).ToList();
```

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23911301/what-are-the-difference-between-entityfunctions-truncatetime-and-dbfunctions-tru

Comment: The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Answer (score 23):

`EntityFunctions` is obsolete. Consider using `DbFunctions` instead.

```
var eventsCustom = eventCustomRepository.FindAllEventsCustomByUniqueStudentReference(userDevice.UniqueStudentReference)
   .Where(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DateTimeStart) == currentDate.Date);
```

Answer (score 19):

I would like to add a solution, that have helpt me to solve this problem in entity framework:

```
var eventsCustom = eventCustomRepository.FindAllEventsCustomByUniqueStudentReference(userDevice.UniqueStudentReference)
                .Where(x =>  x.DateTimeStart.Year == currentDateTime.Year &&
                             x.DateTimeStart.Month== currentDateTime.Month &&
                             x.DateTimeStart.Day == currentDateTime.Day
    );
```

I hope that it helps.

Answer (score 8):

Always use EntityFunctions.TruncateTime() for  both x.DateTimeStart and currentDate.
such as :

```
var eventsCustom = eventCustomRepository.FindAllEventsCustomByUniqueStudentReference(userDevice.UniqueStudentReference).Where(x => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DateTimeStart) == EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(currentDate));
```

Answer (score 7):

Just use simple properties.

```
var tomorrow = currentDateTime.Date + 1;  
var eventsCustom = eventCustomRepository.FindAllEventsCustomByUniqueStudentReference(userDevice.UniqueStudentReference)
                            .Where(x =>  x.DateTimeStart >= currentDateTime.Date 
                                   and x.DateTimeStart < tomorrow);
```

If future dates are not possible in your app, then **>= x.DateTimeStart >= currentDateTime.Date** is sufficient.

if you have more complex date comparisons, then check [Canonical functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738626.aspx)
and if you have EF6+ [DB functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)

More Generally - For people searching for issues [Supported Linq methods in EF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550)
can explain similar issues with linq statements that work on Memory base Lists but not in EF.

Answer (score 5):

**Simplified:**

```
DateTime time = System.DateTime.Now;
ModelName m = context.TableName.Where(x=> DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.Date) == time.Date)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the bellow code for using EF6:

```
(DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.User.LeaveDate.Value)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with `Entity Framework 6.1.3`

But with different scenario. My model property is of type nullable `DateTime`

```
DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
```

So I need to query on today's date to check all the record, so this what works for me. Which means I need to truncate both records to get the proper query on `DbContext`:

```
Where(w => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(w.CreatedDate) == DbFunctions.TruncateTime(DateTime.Now);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be:

```
var eventsCustom = eventCustomRepository.FindAllEventsCustomByUniqueStudentReference(userDevice.UniqueStudentReference).AsEnumerable()
   .Where(x => x.DateTimeStart.Date == currentDate.Date).AsQueryable();
```

Answer (score -2):

I've faced this same issue and it seems that it is really caused by the presence of a call to the `.Date` property within the `Where` method. When removed, the error disappears. Consider that calling the `.Date` property on any side of the comparison operator causes this error. Calling the `.Date` property outside and before the `Where` method is enough to solve this error.

Comment: *When removed, the error disappears* -- Yeah, but they *need* this `.Date` call, or an alternative, and not outside the `Where`. They already know it throws an exception. It doesn't "seem" to be caused by `.Date`, it *is* caused by it.

Comment: As already said, you can call the Date property before the Where and this solves it

Comment: How would you call `x.DateTimeStart.Date` outside the `Where`?

Comment: Using a `Select`

Comment: Just show how you make the code in the question run with your ideas. Words aren't convincing.