# What are the difference between EntityFunctions.TruncateTime and DbFunctions.TruncateTime methods?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

What are are the difference between:

```
EntityFunctions.TruncateTime
```

and

```
DbFunctions.TruncateTime methods?
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is no difference. `EntityFunctions` is the class that appears in the versions of the Entity Framework that are built in to the .NET Framework (up through .NET 4.5). The `DbFunctions` class was introduced in Entity Framework 6 that is shipped separately from the .NET Framework.
For any new applications using versions of EF starting with 6.0, you should use the `DbFunctions` class, as the other class (and much of the built-in EF library) has been obsoleted in favor of the separately deployed versions.

Both functions are merely proxy calls that are translated into the underlying canonical functions within the Entity Framework model and, eventually, into SQL calls.