# C# - Compare DateTime without Time on LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

```
[Route("api/sensors/{id}/{date}/Measurements")]
public IEnumerable<Measurement> GetMeasurements(int id, DateTime date)//date == "11:01:2016 00:00:00"
{
    return _unitOfWork.MeasurementRepository.Get(orderBy: e => e.Where(ex => ex.SensorId == id).Where(a => a.Time == date).OrderBy(tx => tx.Time));
    //a.Time = 11:01:2016 00:00:00, ..., 11:01:2016 00:15:00, ...,11:01:2016 00:30:00, ...,11:01:2016 00:45:00, ...
}
```

I have to return all measurement of the searched day (DateTime date), but I don't know how to compare the two DateTimes without the Time...

If I use `a.Time.Date == date.Date`, this error appears :
[image]

Comment: LINQ to what? In LINQ to Objects you can simply compare the `.Date` properties. In LINQ to EF you need to use  [DbFunctions.TruncateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.truncatetime(v=vs.113).aspx) to generate the equivalent SQL

Comment: Is the query going to the database or only on a list of pocos?

Comment: I edited my question...

Comment: Then use DbFunctions.TruncateTime

Comment: See [The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14601775/2594597)

Comment: @LeonidVasilyev that's [the older name of DbFunctions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23911301/what-are-the-difference-between-entityfunctions-truncatetime-and-dbfunctions-tru)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this

```
.Where(a => a.Time >= date.From() && a.Time <= date.To())
```

Using Helper Methods

```
 public static DateTime From(this DateTime value)
 {
     return new DateTime((value.Year, value.Month, value.Day);
 }

 public static DateTime To(this DateTime value)
 {
     return new DateTime(value.Year, value.Month, value.Day, 23, 59, 59);
 }
```

Comment: You can change `From` to `return value.Date;` (or just use `value.Date` directly instead of having an extension method) and `To` to `return value.Date.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1);` -- or simply `return value.Date.AddDays(1);` and then filter `a.Time < date.To()` (instead of `<=`). - Or `a.Time < date.Date.AddDays(1)`.

Comment: Btw.: all the `DateTime.AddXXX` methods return a **new** `DateTime` object and **don't change** the value they're used on. See also: [DateTime.AddDays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.datetime.adddays.aspx)

Comment: That's simply wrong. You *can* compare dates, just as you can in T-SQL, by truncating time or casting to date. There are multiple duplicate questions in SO. In fact, if the underlying column type was `date` a date comparison wouldn't need any conversions

Comment: This is simply wrong on many levels. Firstly, the Expression does not compile (at least not on EF5, not sure if this was fixed in EF7). Secondly `DbFunction.TruncateTime` was included in EF specifically for this situation.

Answer (score 2):

I have come across this issue before too. Luckily there is a fairly easy solution.

The `DateTime` struct provides a `Date` property for just this occasion.

> Property Value
>   Type: System.DateTime
>   A new object with the same date as this instance, and the time value set to 12:00:00 midnight (00:00:00).
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx

Which means you can simply do this

```
Where(a => a.Time.Date == date.Date)
```

Comment: This would only work on LINQ to Objects. In LINQ to EF it would throw an exception as the comparison can't be translated to SQL as-is. Even worse, in LINQ to SQL all data would be loaded in memory and the Date comparison would be performed in memory

Comment: I edited my question..

Answer (score -1):

Just use the `Date` property of the `DateTime`. This property does not entirely ignore time but will assume that the time is midnight.

Comment: I edited my question..

Answer (score -1):

Try using `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime` or in EF 6.0 it has been replaced with `DbFunctions.TruncateTime`, and then compare that with the known date converted to short date string (`date.ToShortDateString()`).

So:

```
[Route("api/sensors/{id}/{date}/Measurements")]
public IEnumerable<Measurement> GetMeasurements(int id, DateTime date)//date == "11:01:2016 00:00:00"
{
    return _unitOfWork.MeasurementRepository.Get(orderBy: e =>
        e.Where(ex => ex.SensorId == id).Where
        (a => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(a.Time) == date.ToShortDateString())
        .OrderBy(tx => tx.Time));
}
```

Comment: Your code does the *opposite* of what you propose. Instead of comparing dates, it compares date with an arbitrary string

Comment: What is the arbitrary string? The date.ToShortDateString() is specifically a parameter passed into the OP's function. This compares ONLY the date of the 'Time' property to ONLY the date of the date parameter.