# My EF query can't return the datetime in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, datetime

I have this database as you can see :

[image]

In My code i want to return some of these records with datetime condition as you can see :

```
private void lblSubmitDate_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  DateTime subDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(lblSubmitDate.EditValue).Date;
            gridControlDocument.DataSource =
                new BindingList<Document>(_documentRepository
                .Get()
                .Where(i => i.SubmitDateTime==subDateTime)
                .ToList())
                { AllowNew = true };
}
```

But no records returned.

The image of my input :

[image]

The result in sqlprofiler :

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Number] AS [Number], 
    [Extent1].[Class] AS [Class], 
    [Extent1].[Discipline] AS [Discipline], 
    [Extent1].[Unit] AS [Unit], 
    [Extent1].[SubmitDateTime] AS [SubmitDateTime]
    FROM [dbo].[Documents] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[SubmitDateTime] = @p__linq__0',N'@p__linq__0 datetime2(7)',@p__linq__0='2016-07-27 00:00:00'
```

Comment: Well is `subDateTime` a value inside the SubmitDateTime column? (aka, should it return rows by finding an equivalent?)

Comment: @MarkC. the subdatetime is a value that the user can select from datetimepicker

Comment: Right, but what is the value of `subDateTime`? And if you have SQL Server profile - what is the query that EF produces?

Comment: @MarkC. let me check in sqlprofiler .

Comment: @MarkC. I added to my post

Comment: You're using a `DateTime` data type, but only extracting the `.Date` from it. Try to remove the `.Date`

Comment: @MarkC. you mean  DateTime subDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(lblSubmitDate.EditValue);
            gridControlDocument.DataSource = new BindingList<Document>(_documentRepository.Get().Where(i => i.SubmitDateTime==subDateTime).ToList()) { AllowNew = true };

Comment: Yeah, that should do it. That should keep the Time portion of the `subDateTime` variable and match your `WHERE` clause as you're expecting it to

Comment: Can you post a picture of the value of `subDateTime` while debugging? And what the updated generated SQL is from Profiler?

Comment: @MarkC. i added to  my post

Comment: Okay 1 more question: what is the value of `lblSubmitDate.EditValue` ?

Comment: @MarkC. that is 7/27/2016

Comment: Where is the Time component of it? That's just a date. You need to get the Date AND Time from your datetime picker.

Comment: @MarkC. no i just want to get the date

Comment: @MarkC. in fact in this query i need the records that have a equal date with my datepicker

Comment: I apologize - I had misread your question out of haste. Did you try the answer below?

Comment: @MarkC. you are welcome ,yes but i got an error

Comment: Okay, you can delete the screen shot from your answer and the generated SQL, but in their place can you provide some information about the error?

Comment: @MarkC. An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

Additional information: The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Comment: Can you try this? `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(i. SubmitDateTime) == subDateTime `

Comment: @MarkC. you mean this Where(i => i.TruncateTime(i.SubmitDateTime) == subDateTime)

Comment: Yeah, is that a valid function for you?

Comment: @MarkC. No unfortunately

Comment: @MarkC. i remove EntityFunctions from your code and because of that the function can't resolve

Comment: @MarkC. But when i add it works

Comment: Glad you figured it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Josh said is correct.

> You will never retrieve any values because you are parsing the
>   DateTime, but then taking only the Date portion. This means the Time
>   portion will be 00:00:00:

You have to use `EntityFunction.TruncateTime` to get only the Date

```
gridControlDocument.DataSource = 
          new BindingList<Document>(_documentRepository
          .Get()
          .Where(i => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(i.SubmitDateTime)==subDateTime)
          .ToList()) { AllowNew = true };
```

Comment: Just a note: depending on the version of Entity Framework used, one might have to use DbFunctions, rather than EntityFunctions, as noted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23911301/534109).

Answer (score 1):

You will never retrieve any values because you are parsing the `DateTime`, but then taking only the `Date` portion. This means the `Time` portion will be 00:00:00:

```
DateTime subDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(lblSubmitDate.EditValue).Date;
```

When you try to select the rows, you are comparing to `SubmitDateTime`s that have a time component:

```
gridControlDocument.DataSource = new BindingList<Document>(_documentRepository.Get().Where(i => i.SubmitDateTime==subDateTime).ToList()) { AllowNew = true };
```

You need to compare the `Date` portion from the database field with the parsed `Date` from the user selection.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

Additional information: The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Comment: DateTime.Date can't be translated in an SQL statement (at the moment), so yeah, can't use `.Date` unless you've enumerated the result (in which case you're querying an object dataset, not the database).

Comment: I could have sworn they had added that binding. Removed that from my answer so that no one gets confused.