# C#: Return any item that matches the condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a method like this:

```
    public ActionResult ShowAvailableSpots(int Id, DateTime ArrivalDate, DateTime LeaveDate)
    {
        var query2 = db.Spots
            .Where(c => db.Reservations.Any(r =>
                           DbFunctions.TruncateTime(ArrivalDate) <= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(r.ArrivalDate) && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(LeaveDate) <= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(r.ArrivalDate)
                        || DbFunctions.TruncateTime(ArrivalDate) >= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(r.LeaveDate)
            )).ToList();

        ViewBag.StartingDate = ArrivalDate;
        ViewBag.EndingDate = LeaveDate;
        ViewBag.AvailableSpots = query2;

        ViewBag.CampingSpotId = new SelectList(query2, "CampingSpotId", "SpotName");

        return View();
    }
```

It determines wether any of the reservations match the date criteria. If they don't match, then the list with Campingspots is returned.

The problem is, that it is returning ALL spots or NONE spots instead of just the spots that are available. This is due to the .Any method. How can I filter out the campingspots that are not available?

Comment: In your lambda, you have `c => ...` but you're not using `c` anywhere, so the `Any` condition is always evaluating to the same thing. You need to use `c` somewhere in your lambda, but not knowing how spots relate to reservations it's hard to help. You probably need a `Where` clause on your reservations to select reservations that belong to the spot `c`.

Comment: I thought if I would add `&& c.CampingSpotId == r.CampingSpotId` to the expression that would help, but I'm afraid not. Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: Well, you certainly are going to need that to get the right result. Maybe the rest of your condition has a problem. I notice you're using && and ||, but generally the order of operations of something like `a && b || c` is equivalent to `(a && b) || c`, but maybe you want `a && (b || c)`. Try putting parenthesis into your condition to see if that solves your problem.

Comment: The rest of my condition evaluates fine until i add `&& c.CampingSpotId == r.CampingSpotId` doesn't matter in what position or where the parentheses are.

Comment: Are you sure you are writing the right condition ..?? Arrival date and Leave date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var query2 = db.Spots.Where(c => db.Reservations
                                   .Where(r => c.CampingSpotId == r.CampingSpotId)
                                   .All(r => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(LeaveDate) <= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(r.ArrivalDate)
                                          || DbFunctions.TruncateTime(ArrivalDate) >= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(r.LeaveDate))
                   )).ToList();
```

The inner `Where` statement says we're only checking the reservations that apply to that camping spot, and the `All` statement checks to make sure that every reservation for that campsite is outside the window we're interested in.

Comment: Brilliant. After the All i only needed to add `All(r => ...)` That .All statement was what I was looking for. Thank you!